# Cloudformation circular dependency - Route53 and Cloudfront

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

Trying to configure a Route53 and Cloudfront resource but they seem to have an implicit circular dependency on each other. Is there an elegant solution for it?

The snippet of my cloudformation template is below:

```
  AppDnsRecord:
    Type: "AWS::Route53::RecordSetGroup"
    DependsOn: CloudFrontDistributionApp
    Properties:
      HostedZoneName: example.com.
      RecordSets:
        - Name: !Sub "app-${StackName}.example.com."
          Type: CNAME
          TTL: "60"
          ResourceRecords:
            - !GetAtt "CloudFrontDistributionApp.DomainName"

  CloudFrontDistributionApp:
    Type: "AWS::CloudFront::Distribution"
    Properties:
      DistributionConfig:
        Aliases:
          - !Sub "app-${StackName}.example.com"
    # ...
```

The issue is that the CNAME record depends on the Cloudfront's domain name and has a `dependsOn`. However the Cloudfront's `Aliases` configuration requires the `CNAME` to exist.

Comment: Do you get any error? btw, don't need `DependsOn` in `AppDnsRecord`, as you already have `GetAtt` to `CloudFrontDistributionApp`.

Comment: This is the error but I think it's misleading cause the alias is completely new: `One or more aliases specified for the distribution includes an incorrectly configured DNS record that points to another CloudFront distribution. You must update the DNS record to correct the problem. For more information, see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/CNAMEs.html#alternate-domain-names-restrictions (Service: AmazonCloudFront; Status Code: 409; Error Code: CNAMEAlreadyExists; Request ID: 39e3a726-5dc8-48f9-a9bf-7e522836b200)`

Comment: If I create the stack without the `Aliases` property and then update the stack with it there then it's fine.

Comment: I'm implementing my own R53 and CF setup in CFN to check this. Need few more minutes. But I already can confirm you can create CF discro with aliases, without having R54 hosted zone record for that.

Comment: When I tried creating just a CF distro with a CNAME (subdomain) it didn't work with a similar message to my original issue. 

I had a look at our company's Route53 RecordSets and we have a CNAME that points to `*.example.com`, and also a CF distro with a `*.example.com` CNAME. Could that be the issue?

Comment: I should be A record, according to [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-to-cloudfront-distribution.html#routing-to-cloudfront-distribution-config). I created CF distro with alias name. It does not require R53 record to exist at the time of creation. Now I'm trying to create matching R53 record set.

Comment: Your A type record (Alias enabled) should point to DomainName of your CF distro (e.g. d1yibkq6fpd3u2.cloudfront.net). Also you will need SSL certificate correctly set in `ViewerCertificate` in ` AWS::CloudFront::Distribution`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions @Marcin. After playing around with the configurations, it's the wildcard record, `*.example.com` that was causing the error. With it there the creation fails, without it the creation succeeds.

Comment: No problem. Did it work?